# Getting an OpenVPN connection through restrictive firewall

Tags: networking, vpn, firewall, openvpn

First of all, when I try to connect from my phone through my mobile network using the same configuration everything works fine, so the configuration seems to be correct.

However, when I try to access it via a corporate network I can't get a connection.

```
> Mon Nov 21 11:48:35 2016 UDPv4 link local: [undef] 
> Mon Nov 21 11:48:35 2016 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET][server]:1194
> Mon Nov 21 11:49:35 2016 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity) 
> Mon Nov 21 11:49:35 2016 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
```

Things I've tried:

- using ports 443, 80 instead of 1194
- using TCP instead of UDP

Is there anything I could do, or should I write this up as a loss?

Comment: Can you see in your log files your connection attempt from the pc? The log files *may* be in */var/log*, in */etc/openvpn*, or somewhere if you have chosen a non-standard directory.

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely that the corporate network you are using is actively blocking vpn connections using various possible ways. This is very standard practice in today's network security requirements.

Any non standard ports are usually blocked.

The only way you could bypass it is to use an https vpn client if it isn't already explicitly banned on the network. Just using the port 443 will not work.

In the place I previously worked we actively blocked all urls and ips associated with https vpn proiders suck as logmein, hamachi etc

Good luck I hope you find a way around, If there is "Guest WiFi" available in your corporate network i suggest you try that. Usually a lot less restricted.